# how to decompress data in R

Tags: r

here is my string and it's compressed data

string = `"aGVsbG8gdGhlcmU="`

compressed data look like this `[B@2c9f9fb0`

this is the code which i used

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(input.length());
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
    gzip.write(input.getBytes());
    gzip.close();
    byte[] compressed = bos.toByteArray();
```

now i want to decompress this in R (i am passing compressed data via API from Java to R)

i have tried with many libs but i  am not able to do that

code i tried in `R`

```
strsplit(memDecompress(txt.gz, "g", asChar = TRUE), "\n")[[1]]
```

many more `libs` like  `wavethresh`

but it did not help

please suggest me how i do that

Thanks

Comment: I tried to recreate the `gzip` of your string in R. 
Consequently, decopressing it and `rawToChar` works. Could you try that?

`txt <- memCompress("aGVsbG8gdGhlcmU=", type = c("gzip")); rawToChar(memDecompress(txt, type = "gzip"))`

Comment: @JeroenColin hii , the string you used it is not coming like that , compress and uncompressed funs works indivudual in R and Java , but when i pass compress data from Java to R , that  time problem occurs

Comment: @JeroenColin compressed string is coming from Java

Comment: @JeroenColin   there is one more compressed  for `aGVsbG8gdGhlcmU=`  and it is `H4sIAAAAAAAAAMtIzcnJVyjJSC1KBQBQ6RJtCwAAAA==`  ,  could you able convert that compressed in to actual one

Comment: could you provide a real example of the text.gz file that needs to be decompressed?

Comment: @JeroenColin in simple words -:  `String encoded = Base64.encodeBytes(String.valueOf("hello world").getBytes(),Base64.GZIP);` this i pass in R from java